# how implement acra to activity?

Tags: android, acra

How to implement acra error report on activity or something else? I know it must be on class that extends application, but is it possible to add acra to activity?

I'm getting the following error

> cannot be cast to *android.app.application*

This is my code

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "http://test.com/cekErr",

            formUriBasicAuthLogin = "GENERATED_USERNAME_WITH_WRITE_PERMISSIONS",
            formUriBasicAuthPassword = "GENERATED_PASSWORD",
    formKey = "",
    customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
            ReportField.REPORT_ID,
            ReportField.BUILD,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE
    },
    resToastText = R.string.app_name
)

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getNewDefaultConfig(this.getApplication()); 
    config.setResToastText(R.string.app_name);
    ACRA.setConfig(config);

    ACRA.init(this.getApplication());
    Map<ReportField, String> mapping = new HashMap<ReportField, String>();
    mapping.put(ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, "myAppVerCode");
    mapping.put(ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, "myAppVerName");
    mapping.put(ReportField.LOGCAT, "myAppErr");
    // ...
    mapping.put(ReportField.USER_EMAIL, "userEmail");
    // remove any default report sender
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().removeAllReportSenders();
    // create your own instance with your specific mapping
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().addReportSender(
            new HttpPostSender
            ("http://test.com/cekErr"
                    , mapping));
}
```

Comment: fallow this [link](http://www.toptal.com/android/automated-android-crash-reports-with-acra-and-cloudant)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add acra to and activity you need to configure to an application class level.

MyApplication.java

```
import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

@ReportsCrashes(
    formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
    formUri = "http://www.backendofyourchoice.com/reportpath"
)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

Application

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"                   android:name="MyApplication">
```

Permition

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

follow this basic [setup](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)

Answer (score 2):

No. ACRA is added to your entire application.
If you don't already have an Application class just create one that extends from Application.

Comment: don't forget to specify it in the AndroidManifest.xml as your Application class.

Answer (score 1):

As colleagues already have told you, ACRA is added to entire application. So, add ACRA to your app, but use it only in desired Activity.